# Ubuntu takes very long time to boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

Not always but sometimes Ubuntu takes specifically very long time to boot and load the desktop environment, even though I am using a LTS distribution.What could be the possible reasons and techniques to decrease the boot time?
Here I've added my log as well, but I have no idea about understanding and making use of it to boost the speed.

 Thank you in advance

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-74-generic (buildd@lcy01-08) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:02 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 3.13.0-74.118-generic 3.13.11-ckt30)
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   NSC Geode by NSC
[    0.000000]   Cyrix CyrixInstead
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   Transmeta GenuineTMx86
[    0.000000]   Transmeta TransmetaCPU
[    0.000000]   UMC UMC UMC UMC
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009c3ff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009c400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000dc000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007727bfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007727c000-0x0000000077281fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077282000-0x00000000773edfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000773ee000-0x000000007740efff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007740f000-0x000000007746efff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007746f000-0x000000007746ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077470000-0x00000000774f0fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000774f1000-0x000000007770efff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007770f000-0x0000000077716fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077717000-0x000000007771efff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007771f000-0x000000007777ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077780000-0x000000007779efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007779f000-0x00000000777e1fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000777e2000-0x00000000777fefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000777ff000-0x00000000777fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000077800000-0x000000007bffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f7fff000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fc804000-0x00000000fc804fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec0ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed003ff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.6 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD. RV411/RV511/E3511/S3511/RV711/E3411/RV411/RV511/E3511/S3511/RV711/E3411, BIOS 04PA.M006.20110615.
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x77800 max_arch_pfn = 0x1000000
[    0.000000] MTRR default type: uncachable
[    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[    0.000000]   C0000-CFFFF write-protect
[    0.000000]   D0000-FFFFF write-through
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   0 disabled
[    0.000000]   1 base 078000000 mask FF8000000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   2 base 000000000 mask F80000000 write-back
[    0.000000]   3 disabled
[    0.000000]   4 disabled
[    0.000000]   5 disabled
[    0.000000]   6 disabled
[    0.000000]   7 disabled
[    0.000000] x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
[    0.000000] original variable MTRRs
[    0.000000] reg 1, base: 1920MB, range: 128MB, type UC
[    0.000000] reg 2, base: 0GB, range: 2GB, type WB
[    0.000000] total RAM covered: 1920M
[    0.000000] Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 256M    num_reg: 2      lose cover RAM: 0G
[    0.000000] New variable MTRRs
[    0.000000] reg 0, base: 0GB, range: 2GB, type WB
[    0.000000] reg 1, base: 1920MB, range: 128MB, type UC
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f6660-0x000f666f] mapped at [c00f6660]
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] initial memory mapped: [mem 0x00000000-0x01ffffff]
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [c0098000] 98000 size 16384
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000]  [mem 0x00000000-0x000fffff] page 4k
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x37800000-0x379fffff]
[    0.000000]  [mem 0x37800000-0x379fffff] page 2M
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x34000000-0x377fffff]
[    0.000000]  [mem 0x34000000-0x377fffff] page 2M
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00100000-0x33ffffff]
[    0.000000]  [mem 0x00100000-0x001fffff] page 4k
[    0.000000]  [mem 0x00200000-0x33ffffff] page 2M
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x37a00000-0x37bfdfff]
[    0.000000]  [mem 0x37a00000-0x37bfdfff] page 4k
[    0.000000] BRK [0x01b9d000, 0x01b9dfff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x35c1e000-0x36e06fff]
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 000f65a0 000024 (v02 PTLTD )
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 777f4296 00005C (v01 SECCSD LH43STAR 06040000  LTP 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 777e4000 0000F4 (v03 INTEL  CALPELLA 06040000 PTEC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 777e5000 00A8F4 (v02 Intel  CALPELLA 06040000 INTL 20060912)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 7779bfc0 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 777fed86 000038 (v01 INTEL  CALPELLA 06040000 PTEC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 777fedbe 00003C (v01 INTEL  CALPELLA 06040000 PTEC 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 777fedfa 000176 (v01 SECCSD LH43STAR 06040000  LTP 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 777fef70 000068 (v01 PTLTD  ? APIC   06040000  LTP 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BOOT 777fefd8 000028 (v01 PTLTD  $SBFTBL$ 06040000  LTP 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 777e3000 0009F1 (v01  PmRef    CpuPm 00003000 INTL 20061109)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] 1020MB HIGHMEM available.
[    0.000000] 891MB LOWMEM available.
[    0.000000]   mapped low ram: 0 - 37bfe000
[    0.000000]   low ram: 0 - 37bfe000
[    0.000000] BRK [0x01b9e000, 0x01b9efff] PGTABLE
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x00001000-0x00ffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x01000000-0x37bfdfff]
[    0.000000]   HighMem  [mem 0x37bfe000-0x777fffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00001000-0x0009bfff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00100000-0x7727bfff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x77282000-0x773edfff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x7740f000-0x7746efff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x7770f000-0x77716fff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x7771f000-0x7777ffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x7779f000-0x777e1fff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x777ff000-0x777fffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 488592
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c19a3880, node_mem_map f4d2e020
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 32 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3995 pages, LIFO batch:0
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1752 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 224254 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000]   HighMem zone: 2041 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   HighMem zone: 260343 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] Using APIC driver default
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x04] enabled)
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x01] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 1, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 high edge)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] nr_irqs_gsi: 40
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009c000-0x0009cfff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009d000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000dc000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x7c000000-0xf7ffefff] available for PCI devices
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8 nr_cpumask_bits:8 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 14 pages/cpu @f7bd9000 s35520 r0 d21824 u57344
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s35520 r0 d21824 u57344 alloc=14*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 486808
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic root=UUID=4461d5d7-08c2-401a-b871-fb78bb667679 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Initializing CPU#0
[    0.000000] allocated 3915768 bytes of page_cgroup
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:2304 nr_irqs:512 16
[    0.000000] CPU 0 irqstacks, hard=f7008000 soft=f700a000
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.004000] tsc: Detected 2128.185 MHz processor
[    0.000002] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4256.37 BogoMIPS (lpj=8512740)
[    0.000004] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000035] Security Framework initialized
[    0.000050] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.000052] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.000104] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000106] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.275062] \_SB_.PCI0:_OSC invalid UUID
[    0.275063] _OSC request data:1 1f 0 
[    0.275068] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    0.276042] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.276046] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-3e]
[    0.276048] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.276051] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.276053] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.276055] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
[    0.276057] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    0.276059] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.276061] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x7c000000-0xfeafffff]
[    0.276070] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:0044] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.276091] DMAR: BIOS has allocated no shadow GTT; disabling IOMMU for graphics
[    0.276190] pci 0000:00:02.0: [8086:0046] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.276204] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfc3fffff 64bit]
[    0.276212] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.276217] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x20: [io  0x1800-0x1807]
[    0.276365] pci 0000:00:16.0: [8086:3b64] type 00 class 0x078000
[    0.276397] pci 0000:00:16.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc805800-0xfc80580f 64bit]
[    0.276502] pci 0000:00:16.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.276626] pci 0000:00:1a.0: [8086:3b3c] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.276653] pci 0000:00:1a.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc806000-0xfc8063ff]
[    0.276768] pci 0000:00:1a.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.276881] pci 0000:00:1b.0: [8086:3b56] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.276904] pci 0000:00:1b.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc800000-0xfc803fff 64bit]
[    0.277008] pci 0000:00:1b.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.277084] pci 0000:00:1b.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.277123] pci 0000:00:1c.0: [8086:3b42] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.277229] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.277306] pci 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.277348] pci 0000:00:1c.3: [8086:3b48] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.277454] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.277531] pci 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.277581] pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:3b34] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.277608] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc806400-0xfc8067ff]
[    0.277722] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.277828] pci 0000:00:1e.0: [8086:2448] type 01 class 0x060401
[    0.277965] pci 0000:00:1e.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.278004] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:3b09] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.278217] pci 0000:00:1f.2: [8086:3b29] type 00 class 0x010601
[    0.278246] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x10: [io  0x1818-0x181f]
[    0.278257] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x14: [io  0x180c-0x180f]
[    0.278269] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x18: [io  0x1810-0x1817]
[    0.278281] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x1c: [io  0x1808-0x180b]
[    0.278293] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x20: [io  0x1820-0x183f]
[    0.278305] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x24: [mem 0xfc805000-0xfc8057ff]
[    0.278376] pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot
[    0.278482] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:3b30] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.278505] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc806800-0xfc8068ff 64bit]
[    0.278537] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [io  0x1840-0x185f]
[    0.278665] pci 0000:00:1f.6: [8086:3b32] type 00 class 0x118000
[    0.278696] pci 0000:00:1f.6: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc804000-0xfc804fff 64bit]
[    0.279018] pci 0000:02:00.0: [14e4:4727] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.279052] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfc500000-0xfc503fff 64bit]
[    0.279217] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.279219] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.283719] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-03]
[    0.283729] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.283739] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc500000-0xfc5fffff]
[    0.283753] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfcc00000-0xfcdfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.283857] pci 0000:04:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.283876] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x3000-0x30ff]
[    0.283906] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xfc900000-0xfc900fff 64bit pref]
[    0.283924] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xfca04000-0xfca07fff 64bit pref]
[    0.293577] pci 0000:3f:00.1: [8086:2d01] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.293625] pci 0000:3f:02.0: [8086:2d10] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.293669] pci 0000:3f:02.1: [8086:2d11] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.293712] pci 0000:3f:02.2: [8086:2d12] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.293755] pci 0000:3f:02.3: [8086:2d13] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.293809] pci_bus 0000:3f: on NUMA node 0
[    0.294026] ACPI: Enabled 5 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
[    0.294034] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0: notify handler is installed
[    0.294114] ACPI: \_SB_.CPBG: notify handler is installed
[    0.294123] Found 2 acpi root devices
[    0.294385] ACPI : EC: GPE = 0x17, I/O: command/status = 0x66, data = 0x62
[    0.294525] ACPI : EC: 0 stale EC events cleared
[    0.294657] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[    0.294660] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.294664] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.294666] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[    0.294864] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.294902] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.294926] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.294947] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.294956] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.294980] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.295091] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.297463] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    0.297554] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009c400-0x0009ffff]
[    0.297556] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x7727c000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297560] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x773ee000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297563] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x7746f000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297566] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x77717000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297568] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x77780000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297570] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x777e2000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297572] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x77800000-0x77ffffff]
[    0.297665] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.297667] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.297668] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.297680] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.297794] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
[    0.297800] hpet0: 8 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
[    0.299836] Switched to clocksource hpet
[    0.306629] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.306662] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.306680] ACPI: bus type PNP registered
[    0.307041] pnp 00:00: [dma 4]
[    0.307072] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
[    0.307099] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
[    0.307210] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
[    0.307243] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
[    0.307309] system 00:04: [io  0x0680-0x069f] has been reserved
[    0.307312] system 00:04: [io  0x0500-0x050f] has been reserved
[    0.307314] system 00:04: [io  0x0600-0x0603] has been reserved
[    0.307317] system 00:04: [io  0xffff] has been reserved
[    0.307320] system 00:04: [io  0x0400-0x047f] could not be reserved
[    0.307322] system 00:04: [io  0x1180-0x11ff] has been reserved
[    0.307324] system 00:04: [io  0x164e-0x164f] has been reserved
[    0.307327] system 00:04: [io  0xfe00] has been reserved
[    0.307330] system 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.307391] system 00:05: [io  0x06a0-0x06af] has been reserved
[    0.307394] system 00:05: [io  0x06b0-0x06ff] has been reserved
[    0.307397] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.307446] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.307482] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.307527] pnp 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.307969] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed1c000-0xfed1ffff] has been reserved
[    0.307972] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed13fff] has been reserved
[    0.307975] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed18000-0xfed18fff] has been reserved
[    0.307977] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed19000-0xfed19fff] has been reserved
[    0.307980] system 00:09: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] has been reserved
[    0.307982] system 00:09: [mem 0xf7fff000-0xf7ffffff] has been reserved
[    0.307985] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed3ffff] has been reserved
[    0.307987] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff] has been reserved
[    0.307990] system 00:09: [mem 0xfed45000-0xfed8ffff] has been reserved
[    0.307992] system 00:09: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff] has been reserved
[    0.307995] system 00:09: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfeefffff] could not be reserved
[    0.307998] system 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.308382] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices
[    0.308383] ACPI: bus type PNP unregistered
[    0.308387] PnPBIOS: Disabled by ACPI PNP
[    0.345282] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02-03]
[    0.345287] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.345294] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfc500000-0xfc5fffff]
[    0.345300] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfcc00000-0xfcdfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.345308] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI bridge to [bus 04-05]
[    0.345312] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[    0.345319] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xfc400000-0xfc4fffff]
[    0.345324] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xfc900000-0xfcbfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.345332] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 06]
[    0.345349] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.345351] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.345353] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.345355] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
[    0.345357] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    0.345360] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 9 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.345362] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 10 [mem 0x7c000000-0xfeafffff]
[    0.345364] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 0 [io  0x2000-0x2fff]
[    0.345366] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xfc500000-0xfc5fffff]
[    0.345368] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xfcc00000-0xfcdfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.345371] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 0 [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[    0.345373] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xfc400000-0xfc4fffff]
[    0.345375] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xfc900000-0xfcbfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.345377] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.345379] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.345381] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.345383] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 7 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
[    0.345385] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 8 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    0.345387] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 9 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.345390] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 10 [mem 0x7c000000-0xfeafffff]
[    0.345428] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.345658] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.345674] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.345696] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.345714] TCP: reno registered
[    0.345717] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.345723] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.345775] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.345788] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM
[    0.346393] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    0.346447] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.742234] Freeing initrd memory: 18340K (f5c1e000 - f6e07000)
[    0.742351] Simple Boot Flag at 0x37 set to 0x1
[    0.742505] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x20655, pf=0x10, revision=0x2
[    0.742513] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x20655, pf=0x10, revision=0x2
[    0.742592] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    0.742595] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    0.742837] Initialise system trusted keyring
[    0.742883] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.742896] type=2000 audit(1453567278.624:1): initialized
[    0.767270] bounce pool size: 64 pages
[    0.767281] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.768560] zbud: loaded
[    0.768640] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.768690] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.769192] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[    0.769278] msgmni has been set to 1720
[    0.769344] Key type big_key registered
[    0.769803] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.769806] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.769842] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.769875] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.769877] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.769907] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.770427] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.770445] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.770489] vesafb: mode is 1024x768x32, linelength=4096, pages=0
[    0.770491] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.770493] vesafb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.771617] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, mapped to 0xf8480000, using 3072k, total 3072k
[    1.520711] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.520718] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.520865] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   21.529215] type=1400 audit(1453567300.192:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/unity-lens-askubuntu/unity-askubuntu-daemon" pid=792 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.531003] type=1400 audit(1453567300.196:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.531011] type=1400 audit(1453567300.196:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.531017] type=1400 audit(1453567300.196:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.810062] init: samba4 main process (747) terminated with status 1
[   22.085377] init: Failed to spawn hybrid-gfx main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Slow boot could be any number of things. You will first want to run a memtest (available in grub) to make sure that your memory is okay. You will also want to check your disk usage and general disk health. Once you have an idea of what's causing the slow boot, we will be able to help you further.

Comment: Is it having to run fsck on every reboot. I might try at grub menu removing quiet splash from Linux line and watch boot process. Same info is in logs if you want to review later. That may give a clue as to what is slow, run multiple times before working or outright error.

Answer (score 2):

Check logs:

Older systems with Upstart

```
gksudo gedit /var/log/dmesg
sudo grep -E -i "error|warning" /var/log/dmesg
```

Newer systems with systemd:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Answer (score -1):

In case your installation is encrypted it can happen that because of a good encryption Ubuntu is working slower.

In case your installation is NOT encrypted you can install BleachBit and tidy up your machine with it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Comment: This doesn't try to answer the question. While bleachbit may help with cleaning up a system, there could be other issues affect boot. Instead of offering a slim answer like this, it would be helpful if you were to include a summary of why you think this app would be helpful in this situation, as well as how to use it to the user's advantage in speeding up boot.

Comment: What's the point of `sudo apt-get update` after `sudo apt-get install bleachbit`? Did you just switched the order of the two?